# How to list all of Magento's error messages

Tags: magento

I am currently doing some i18n work for an Enterprise installation of Magento (1.10.1.1) and I am trying to gather a list of the possible error messages that Magento may ever provide to the front-end.  Reason being, so that we can have a translation ready and use it (via a proxy service).

Does anyone have a list of the possible standard error messages or know of a way to generate such a list?  Also if possible, a way of generating the error messages for 3rd party modules also?

Answer (score 1):

Anything passed through translation is a potential candidate. Responsible module developers will provide translation CSVs for their modules which contain all strings. Because this isn't a guarantee, there are several companies who offer or are planning to offer translation modules which parse translatable strings from the files and data. Candidate locations:

- `core_translate` table
- Store scopes for entity data (categories, products, etc.)
- Any node from XML files with a `translate=""` attribute
- Anything in blocks, controllers, and helpers which may be translated

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a list of errors and messages that Magento provides, I ended up doing this:

```
grep -rih "__('" app/code/ | cut -d"'" -f4 | sort | uniq >> messages.txt
grep -rih "Exception($helper>__(" app/code/ | cut -d"'" -f4 | sort | uniq >> messages.txt
```

It was a bit of a messy list, but was able to get most of what I needed from there.